# Strange behaviour when absolutely positioning floated elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to absolutely position some floated divs using this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#wrapper div').each( function( index, item ) {
        alert( $(this).position().left );
        $(this).css({position:'absolute', top:$(this).position().top, left:$(this).position().left});
    });
});
```

What I can't figure out is why when I set position:absolute $(this).position() always returns {top:0, left:0}.  How can I get the proper coordinates and set the position to absolute?

I've set up a jsfiddle to illustrate this http://jsfiddle.net/SxJCb/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Set only `top` and `left` for all the `div`s. Once that has been done, *then* set `position: absolute` on all of them.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/SxJCb/6/

```
$('#wrapper div').each( function( index, item ) {
    $(this).css({top:$(this).position().top, left:$(this).position().left});
}).css({position:'absolute'});
```

---

**Long answer:** *(an explanation of what's going on)*

All the `div`s are floated. As you had it, each `div` was being removed from normal flow by being set to `position: absolute`, so all the subsequent `div`s shifted back a place. So, the second `div` moves to where the first one was, etc.

Here's a slow motion demo of what was happening: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/SxJCb/7/

Comment: I thought it might be something like that going on.  Thanks for the explanation. Setting the position to absolute after works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $("#wrapper div").offset().left; 
var y = $("#wrapper div").offset().top;
```

this can help

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to append 'px' to the end of the top and left properties when setting css values directly.