# Elements position changing after setting position to absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have run into a pretty weird problem that I have managed to fix, but in a disgusting way.

I have the following working code that grabs the left and top of the element (using MooTools). It then uses `setStyles` to copy these measured coordinates into the style attribute. This works pretty well.

But as soon as I set the position to absolute the values in the code above it appear to change.

**Works but horrible:**

```
var Sortable = new Class({
    initialize: function(element, container) {
        // Store the element and its settings
        this.element = element;
        this.size = element.getSize();
        this.position = element.getPosition(container);

        // Set the position
        element.setStyles({
            left: this.position.x,
            top: this.position.y
        });

        setTimeout(this.goAbsolute.bind(this), 0);
    },
    goAbsolute: function() {
        this.element.setStyle('position', 'absolute');
    }
});
```

As you can see, I am using a timeout to separate the left / top setting and the position setting. The following code does not work.

```
var Sortable = new Class({
    initialize: function(element, container) {
        // Store the element and its settings
        this.element = element;
        this.size = element.getSize();
        this.position = element.getPosition(container);

        // Set the position
        element.setStyles({
            left: this.position.x,
            top: this.position.y,
            position: 'absolute'
        });
    }
});
```

So, we can use this.

```
this.size = element.getSize();
```

And `size.x` will equal 100 for example. Then with this added line.

```
this.size = element.getSize();
element.setStyle('position', 'absolute');
```

`size.x` will now equal 0. Even though it was set to absolute after.

I have tried cloning the object and its values.

I have tried putting them all out of scope of each other.

Nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know of a way to do a similar fix but without `setTimeout`? Or is that the best way.

I have tried to explain my problem as best as I can but it is a bit of a strange one. So comment with any questions.

Thank you for any suggestions you may have.

Comment: Care to provide any html this code should be working on ? And how does this sortable function get called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure (I'm not certain because you didn't mention `float: left`) that you're having the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098283/strange-behaviour-when-absolutely-positioning-floated-elements/7098545#7098545), which I answered thoroughly.

In short, you need to firstly set `top` and `left` on all the elements. After doing that, then set `position: absolute` on all the elements.