# Retrieved $().position() changes after updating to position: absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, absolute

I'm figuring out a possible solution for a dynamic crossfade of HTML elements. The core of my problem is a strange behaviour of the jQuery's .position() and updating the css "position" property after retrieving the old position.

I've made a JSFiddle to illustrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/svenhanssen/DDYVs/

```
/*
This works. I'll get a position.top from 0 to 90
*/

$("p").each(function( p ) {
    var position = $(this).position();

    console.log(position.top);
});

/*
This doesn't work. I'll get a position.top of 0 for all elements. Why does the css set effects the position?
*/

$("p").each(function( p ) {
    var position = $(this).position();

    console.log(position.top);

    $(this).css({
        position: "absolute"
    });
});​
```

Somehow changing the css "position" property afterwards effects the old property. Does anyone know the reason why and a possible solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The moment you set a `<p>` to `position: absolute` it is taken out of the document flow, and the next non-absolute `<p>` is moved upwards to take the freed space. Then you get to that just-repositioned `<p>` element, and sure enough its `top` is now `0` (since there are no in-flow elements before it to push it down).

Here's a possible solution:

```
$("p").each(function( p ) {
    var position = $(this).position();

    console.log(position.top);
}).css({
    position: "absolute"
});​
```

Note that now all `<p>` elements are set to `position: absolute` only *after* the loop has rolled.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DDYVs/2/)

Comment: Here's a similar answer where I provide a nice visualization of the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098283/strange-behaviour-when-absolutely-positioning-floated-elements/7098545#7098545

Comment: @lanzz You're absolutely right. I was staring death, but the solution was actually very simple. Thanks.